# Pond for largemouth bass / perch

Tags: fish, ponds

In NE Ohio (Zone 5 - 6) how large of a pond would I need to raise largemouth bass or perch for food production.

What is the minimal depth and diameter required for 100 fish?

Comment: There is some good info on the Virginia DGIF site about [pond size](http://www.dgif.virginia.gov/fishing/pondmanagement/construction.asp) and [stocking fish](http://www.dgif.virginia.gov/fishing/pondmanagement/stocking.asp) which might help.